# Using proxy through a webbrowser navigation

Tags: c#, proxy

Is it possible, to connect to a site using, for example web.Navigate http://google.com through a proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible ? Yes.

[Sample from msdn](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSWebBrowserWithProxy-c8535715) :

> The sample demonstrates how to make WebBrowser use a proxy server.
>
> In Internet Explorer 5 and later, Internet options can be set for on a specific
> connection and process, for example, LAN connection or ADSL connection. Wininet.dll
> contains 4 extern methods (InternetOpen, InternetCloseHandle, InternetSetOption
> and InternetQueryOption) to set and retrieve internet settings.

[Looking for more info](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=webbrowser%20proxy%20c%23) ?